# Performance issues tailing mongoDB Oplog

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently running a script which scans the mongoDB oplog for recent entries and then sends the data to another system. The query looks something like this:

```
db.getCollection('oplog.rs').find({
  ts: { $gt: Timestamp(1512083841, 3225) }
})
```

Where the timestamp is the `ts` of the last record processed

Unfortunately while this works, the query takes as long as 2 seconds to complete, and it pegs the processor on the machine while it's running.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not expert on mongo but why you didn't try to use Mongo 3.6 [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-streams-example/)? they seem to be specifically tailored for your task

Comment: Are you using a tailable cursor (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors) or just re-running the query every time?

Comment: Rerunning the query.

Comment: So I found an answer to this. I was trying to implement this in go, and the driver I'm using has a tail function for capped collections. I believe it's implementing the tailable cursor (link above) in the code. This drastically improved the performance.